# Android softkeyboard issue with input in focus

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, android-softkeyboard

I have an issue with the android softkeyboard overlapping the input fields when in focus. I have tried various solutions but to no avail. My application is built using phonegap I have tried to change the android:windowSoftInputMode to various solutions but everything doesn't work. these are the issues i ahve

1) The login screen input field does not focus into the center of the screen when in focus unless it is typed into. This is when the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan".

2) If android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" the input field does come into the center of the screen but only when typed into and this also breaks the layout of a bottom nav bar which is pushed up by the keyboard.

Does anyone have any advice on what I should do??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is a workaround:

Install com.ionic.keyboard plugin

Set this in your config.xml

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Add this to the bottom of your page

```
<div id="kbs" class="keyboardspace"></div>
```

Give the surrounding element the id "frame"

Add this to your css

```
.keyboardspace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

Now register these two event listeners (I'm using jquery here, but it should also be possible without)

```
var window = angular.element($window);
window.on('native.keyboardshow', function (e) {
   $("#kbs").height(e.keyboardHeight);
   var focus = $(document.activeElement);
   var pos = focus.offset();
   var bottom = pos.top + focus.height() + 10;
   var maxpos = $($window).height() - e.keyboardHeight;
   if (bottom > maxpos) {
       $("#frame").scrollTop(bottom - maxpos);
   }
});
window.on('native.keyboardhide', function () {
  console.log("native.keyboardhide");
  $("#kbs").height(0);
});
```

Note that the frame has to be scrollable for this to work.

Comment: I'm building this on angular. How can I write this in an angular way? Sorry I am so new to this.

Comment: It seems as it is way harder to get the offset with angular. You can either include jQuery in your project or you have to replace the jQuery calls yourself. Angular includes jqLite, so most of the syntax will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You use this code in your Softkeyboard.java:

```
@override
public void onComputeInsets(Insets outInsets){

super.onComputeInsets(outInsets);
if(!isFullscreenMode()){
outInsets.contentTopInsets = outInsets.visibleTopInsets;
}
}
```